# How do I change LAN settings

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Want to change lan settings but it keep throwing me message.

Some settings are managed by your administrator.

[image]

There is no DOMAIN, there is no other users instead of me : which belongs to

[image]

Tried with : gpedit.msc
    Security ZONES.
Also tried directly though REGEDIT.

How to get rid of this i think its malware.

Comment: Try launching the Internet Options control panel from an elevated command prompt (Run As Administrator): `inetcpl.cpl`

Comment: What does this have to do with powershell?

Comment: I get the same message. Tried run as administrator command prompt

Comment: @EBGreen Looking for powershell command to disable those

Comment: Aaah...then your question is actually "How do I change LAN settings through Powershell". Here, let me fix that for you...

Comment: Now, having said that I would make two points. First, stackoverflow is not a script writing service. We are here to help you with specific problems in code that you write. Second, if you cannot change the setting through the GUI then you won't be able to through Powershell either so your root issue still is not a Powershell problem.

Comment: ok EBGreen delete this mark this as not question for stackoverflow. I will ask somewhere else how to disable this functionality.

Comment: You have the ability to delete the question. I don't.